# django/wagtail template errors

Tags: django, wagtail

Django version: 1.7.8; wagtail version: 0.8.8. Getting started (steps):

1. wagtail start mysite
2. cd mysite
3. python manage.py migrate
4. python manage.py createsuperuser
5. python manage.py runserver

Then I open `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and click "Here" to login; get a error page, and the error information is about the template `base.html`, line 17:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">

    <div class="inner">
        <a href="{% url 'wagtailadmin_home' %}" class="logo" title="Wagtail v.{% wagtail_version %}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg" alt="Wagtail" width="80" /><span>{% trans "Dashboard" %}</span></a>

        <form class="nav-search" action="{% url 'wagtailadmin_pages_search' %}" method="get">
            <div>
                <label for="menu-search-q">{% trans "Search" %}</label>
                <input type="text" id="menu-search-q" name="q" placeholder="{% trans 'Search' %}" />
                <button type="submit">{% trans "Search" %}</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        {% main_nav %}    --- ERROR
    </div>

    <nav id="explorer" class="explorer"></nav>

</div>
```

I found `main_nav` is another html template located at a related path `/shared/main_nav.html` so I replaced `{% main_nav %}` with {`% shared.main_nav %}`, then I get the right page.

But when I open other URLs, I will get some same template-related errors.

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: As a bit of extra background - `{% main_nav %}` doesn't have a file path on it because it's not a file include - it's a custom tag defined by `load wagtailadmin_tags` at the top of the template. For more details of the Django template language, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/ . But really, there should be no need to edit that file at all - it's Wagtail internal code, and if you give more details of the error we can suggest further steps.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer, i install wagtail using easy_install, and I think i should get familiar with django firstly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempted fix of `{% main_nav %}` suggests you aren't that familiar with Django. The fact you were able to edit Wagtail's internal files also indicates you're perhaps installing it from Git, rather than with pip or from Pypi, which would normally hide Wagtail's code relatively out of reach.

If you're interested in getting Wagtail up and running quickly, and my assumptions above are correct, you might have a better time by installing the latest *stable* release, 0.8.8, with pip, in a virtualenv, following the instructions here:

http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/index.html